# Preprocessing CSV data using tensorflow DataSet API

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I'm playing around a bit with tensorflow, but am a bit confused about the input pipeline. The data I'm working on is in a large csv file, with 307 columns, of which the first is a string representing a date, and the rest are floats.

I'm running into some problems with preprocessing my data. I want to add a couple of features instead of, but based on, the date string. (specifically, a sine and a cosine representing the time). I also want to group the next 120 values in the CSV row together as one feature, the 96 ones after that as one feature, and base my label off of the remaining values in the CSV.

This is my code for generating the datasets for now:

```
import tensorflow as tf

defaults = []
defaults.append([""])
for i in range(0,306):
  defaults.append([1.0])

def dataset(train_fraction=0.8):
  path = "training_examples_shuffled.csv"

  # Define how the lines of the file should be parsed
  def decode_line(line):
    items = tf.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=defaults)

    datetimeString = items[0]
    minuteFeatures = items[1:121]
    halfHourFeatures = items[121:217]
    labelFeatures = items[217:]

    ## Do something to convert datetimeString to timeSine and timeCosine

    features_dict = {
      'timeSine': timeSine,
      'timeCosine': timeCosine,
      'minuteFeatures': minuteFeatures,
      'halfHourFeatures': halfHourFeatures
    }

    label = [1] # placeholder. I seem to need some python logic here, but I'm 
                  not sure how to apply that to data in tensor format.

    return features_dict, label

  def in_training_set(line):
    """Returns a boolean tensor, true if the line is in the training set."""
    num_buckets = 1000000
    bucket_id = tf.string_to_hash_bucket_fast(line, num_buckets)
    # Use the hash bucket id as a random number that's deterministic per example
    return bucket_id < int(train_fraction * num_buckets)

  def in_test_set(line):
    """Returns a boolean tensor, true if the line is in the training set."""
    return ~in_training_set(line)

  base_dataset = (tf.data
                  # Get the lines from the file.
                  .TextLineDataset(path))

  train = (base_dataset
           # Take only the training-set lines.
           .filter(in_training_set)
           # Decode each line into a (features_dict, label) pair.
           .map(decode_line))

  # Do the same for the test-set.
  test = (base_dataset.filter(in_test_set).map(decode_line))

  return train, test
```

My question now is: how can I access the string in the datetimeString Tensor to convert it to a datetime object? Or is this the wrong place to be doing this? I'd like to use the time and the day of the week as input features.

And secondly: Pretty much the same for the label based on the remaining values of the CSV. Can I just use standard python code for this in some way, or should I be using basic tensorflow ops to achieve what I want, if possible?

Finally, any comments on whether this is a decent way of handling my inputs? Tensorflow is a bit confusing, with old tutorials spread around the internet using deprecated ways of handling inputs.